# Can you run a VM under a tor network?

Tags: security, proxy, virtual-machine, virtualisation

Can I setup on the VM host to redirect all my VM guest networking over Tor?

Answer (score 1):

Have you investigated Whonix as a possibility? Basically two virtual machines, a gateway and a workstation. 1 VM to act as a workstation, the other VM acts as a gateway and funnels all traffic through Tor.

https://www.whonix.org/

Comment: As dsefvonz has noted, you don't necessarily have to use whonix on the workstation VM but you better be confident in your ability to secure that VM if you do choose to go this route. Using whonix on both VM's is a lot more fool proof.

Answer (score 0):

Running Whonix-gateway with a configured dhcp-server would enable you to connect any guest VM (even Android VMs) through Tor.

https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Other_Operating_Systems#Whonix-Android-Workstation (Click "Expand")